# how to check the database is update/modify/changed?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my database

[image]

This is my php code which is used to fetch the data from the table

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_id =  $row['id']; 
    $sql = "SELECT id, ScheduleDate, StartTime,Endtime, Hours,Employeeid 
    FROM empdet WHERE Employeeid ='".$user_id."' ";
    $result = $con->query($sql);     
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        $id=$row["id"]. 
        $date=$row["ScheduleDate"]; 
        $start=$row["StartTime"]; 
        $end=$row["Endtime"];
        $hour=$row["Hours"];
        $Employeeid=$row["Employeeid"];
        list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
        $data[] = array("year"=>$year,
                        "month"=>$month,
                        "day"=>$day,
                        "StartTime"=>$start,
                        "Endtime"=>$end,
                        "Hours"=>$hour );   
        }
            $response = $data;
    }
    else
        {
        $data=1;
        $response = $data;
        }
```

My question is how to find whether the database is modified/changed/updated?

In the users table, if I change the start time from 2:00pm to 3:00 pm of "2018-12-01" it should notify me in echo as the "2018-12-01" has been modified.

Can anyone suggest how to do this with PHP?

Comment: Agree with @apokryfos and how is this question related to android ?

Comment: maintaining a  `updated_at` field ?

Comment: i am sending the echo "2018-12-01" to android activity, and use them in it!
can you suggest a php code to check for a update? @ADM

Comment: i didn't understand bro,@ Deepansh Sachdeva

Comment: remove the android tag from ur question

Answer (score 2):

int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: Firstly that is for the deprecated `mysql` api rather than `mysqli` and secondly that applies to `INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE` operations

Comment: @RamRaider [Really](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)? (for the mysqli part)

Comment: @RingØ - read carefully, it says `int mysql_affected_rows` and the link quoted references `mysql` not `mysqli` api

Comment: @RamRaider Oh ok, my bad. Just wanted to mention that msyqli has, also, a `affected_rows()` method / function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `timestamp` column type in the database which, when set to use auto-update, would give an indication that the record has been updated.

```
alter table `empdet`
    add column `timestamp` timestamp null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp after `Employeeid`;
```

Then you could alter your query to determine if the record is updated

```
select `id`, `scheduledate`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `hours`, `employeeid`,
case 
    when `timestamp` is not null then
        true
    else
        false
end as 'updated'
from `empdet` where `employeeid` ='".$user_id."';
```

However, looking at the original code there appears to be nested loops both trying to process the query result variable `$result` with the inner query re-assigning this variable. As the outer loop is providing an ID for the inner loop it would make more sense perhaps to do a join - but hard to be specific without seeing the previous code and knowing what the original query was.

Comment: thank you sir,but i dont want to add any colomn,is there is any other way to do it please suggest me.

Comment: load the recordset into a session once and check values in the session against values from latest query ( tbh - not a good option ). Is there any reason why you could not add a new column?

Comment: because this is master db,i cannot add/change any structure in it,i can use the values only.

Answer (score 0):

you create a column with timestamp using this query

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `time_stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `column_name`;
```

timestamp create auto time when data enter so you can get lastime of data and checkout max timestamp